# Why background gradient pushing content down?

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I have a class called `bgGradient` which adds a gradient. When `.bgGradient` is added, it's pushing my content down a considerable amount, whereas I basically just want it as the background.

```css
.content {
  padding: 100px 0px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.bgGradient {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgb(92, 156, 155);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(92, 156, 155, 1) 0%, rgba(140, 205, 204, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(92, 156, 155, 1) 0%, rgba(140, 205, 204, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(92, 156, 155, 1) 0%, rgba(140, 205, 204, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#5c9c9b", endColorstr="#8ccdcc", GradientType=1);
}

.bgGradient:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 100vh 0 0 100vw;
  border-color: #fff transparent #fff transparent;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="wrapper bgGradient">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-6 content text-center">
        <h2>this is a test heading</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need extra element, you can consider multiple background:

```css
.content {
  padding: 100px 0px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.bgGradient {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100vh;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,#fff 49.7%,transparent 50%),
    linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(92, 156, 155, 1) 0%, rgba(140, 205, 204, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<div class="wrapper bgGradient">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-6 content text-center">
        <h2>this is a test heading</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also have transparency using clip-path:

```css
.content {
  padding: 100px 0px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.bgGradient {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100vh;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:0;
}
.bgGradient:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(92, 156, 155, 1) 0%, rgba(140, 205, 204, 1) 100%);
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,0 100%,100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<div class="wrapper bgGradient">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-6 content text-center">
        <h2>this is a test heading</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or mask-image:

```css
.content {
  padding: 100px 0px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.bgGradient {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100vh;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:0;
}
.bgGradient:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(92, 156, 155, 1) 0%, rgba(140, 205, 204, 1) 100%);
  -webkit-mask-image:linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 49.8%,#fff 50%);
  mask-image:linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 49.8%,#fff 50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<div class="wrapper bgGradient">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-6 content text-center">
        <h2>this is a test heading</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Legend for showing me three different approaches, much appreciated